# How do I get my React app to point to my Node/Express API in production. Proxy only works in dev.

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx

I'm a bit new to node/react.

I have an API/express node app and in that app I have a react app. The react app has axios.get commands and other API calls. The react app finds the API calls I do and forwards them to the proxy I setup in the package.json of the react app. In dev the proxy looked like this:   "proxy": "http://localhost:3003/" but now that I'm going into production I'm trying to change this proxy to be the URL I'm hosting my node express app in     "proxy": "http://168.235.83.194:83/"

When I moved my project to production I made port 83 the API node app and I made port 84 the react app (with nginx). For whatever reason though, my react app just doesn't know how to do the API requests to the node app.. I'm getting blank data

After googling I come to realize, the 'proxy' setting only applies to requests made to the development server. Normally in production you have a server that gives the initial page html and also serves api requests. So requests to /api/foo naturally work; you don't need to specify a host.

This is the part I'm trying to figure out. If someone can tell me how to setup my app so that /api/foo  naturally works that would be greatly appreciated.

I took a stab at trying to set that up properly. This is probably a complete failure in terms of an approach but it's late and I'm gonna fall asleep on this problem.. I'm supposed to have nginx handle serving both static html and requests in one statement file? I have this so far but I can be way off here...

```
server {
  listen 84;
  server_name 168.235.83.194;


  root /home/el8le/workspace/notes/client/build;

  index index.html index.htm;
  location / {
  }

  location /api{
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://168.235.83.194:83/; //I have nginx hosting my API app on this port. Not even sure if this should be like this?
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

}`
```

Also, I'm actually hosting on those ip addresses if you want to get a better sense of where I am at: 
http://168.235.83.194:84

http://168.235.83.194:83/customers

Answer (score 2):

You will have to supply the actual API URL while making data request. Dev server is able to proxy to a different API URL. So, if the app loads at http://localhost:83 using DEV Server, any data request like /api/customers will go to http://localhost:83/api/customers and dev proxy server will pipe it to http://localhost:84/api/customers.

But in production, when you make the same request it will use base address of your app and try to get the data from http://PRODUCTION_SERVER:83/api/customers.

Correct way to handle this would be to use absolute URL instead of relative URL. And as production and development will have different Base URLs, maintain them in a config variable and then append specific api address to this base address, something like : `${BASE_URL}/api/customers`, where BASE_URL will be http://localhost:84 in DEV and http://PRODUCTION_SERVER:84.